# submit button is not working in asp.net MVC view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, razor

I'm trying to run C# code with the submit button in MVC but I get an error.
When I click 'Connect' button I get this error:

**error message:**

[image]

The model:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace NEW_Tools.Models
{
    public class LocalEnvGuide
    {
        public int id { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "The path field is required")]
        public string mvc_cf_path { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "The path field is required")]
        public string es_cf_path { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "The environment name field is required")]
        public string env_name { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public bool enable_tasker { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**Controller:(LocalEnvGuides.cs)**

```
...
 // POST: LocalEnvGuides/Run
        [HttpPost, ActionName("Run")]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<IActionResult> RunConfirmed(int id)
        {
            var localEnvGuide = await _context.LocalEnvGuide.FindAsync(id);
            string machine_name = Environment.MachineName.ToString();
            string env_name = localEnvGuide.env_name;
            string mvc_cf_path = localEnvGuide.mvc_cf_path;
            string es_cf_path = localEnvGuide.es_cf_path;
            Run.Main(machine_name, env_name, mvc_cf_path, es_cf_path, true);

            ViewBag.Message = string.Format("Hello {0}.", machine_name);
            return View();
        }
```

**View: (Index.cshtml):**

```
@model IEnumerable<NEW_Tools.Models.LocalEnvGuide>

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Index";
}
<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/StyleTable.css">

<h1 class="text-center">Choose the Environment</h1>
<p>
    <a asp-action="Create">
        <input type="submit" value="Enter a new connection" class="btn btn-primary" />
    </a>
</p>

<div class="pricing-box-container">
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
    <div class="pricing-box text-center">
        <p class="price">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.env_name)</p>
        <ul class="features-list">
            <li>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.mvc_cf_path)</li>
            <li>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.es_cf_path)</li>
            <li>Tasker Status:     @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.enable_tasker)</li>
        </ul>
        <a asp-action="Edit" asp-route-id="@item.id">
            <button class="btn-primary">Edit</button>
        </a>
        <a asp-action="Details" asp-route-id="@item.id">
            <button class="btn-primary">Details</button>
        </a>
        <a asp-action="Delete" asp-route-id="@item.id">
            <button class="btn-primary">Delete</button>
        </a>
        <br />

        <a asp-action="Run" asp-route-id="@item.id">
            <input type="submit" value="Connect" class="btn btn-primary" style="background-color:limegreen" />
        </a>    

        

        <a asp-action="Disconnect" asp-route-id="@item.id">
            <input type="submit" value="Disconnect" class="btn btn-primary" style="background-color:red" />
        </a>
    </div>
    }
```

**View: (Run.cshtml):**

```
@model IEnumerable<NEW_Tools.Models.LocalEnvGuide>

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Index";
}


<!DOCTYPE html>

<div class="text-center">
    <h1 class="display-4">You are connected to the environment!</h1>
</div>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Run</title>
</head>
<body>
    @if (ViewBag.Message != null)
    {
        <script type="text/javascript">
            window.onload = function () {
                alert("Congratulations, you have a new connection!");
            };
        </script>
    }
</body>
</html>
<br />

<div class="text-center">
    <a asp-action="Index">
        <input type="submit" value="Back to connections history" class="btn btn-primary" />
    </a>
</div>
```

I would like to get your help with that please, thanks!
(if you need more details, comment and I will add)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`<a>` link can only send httpget request,you can try to use form to replace it:

```
<form method="post" asp-action="Run" asp-route-id="1">
    <input type="submit" value="Connect" class="btn btn-primary" style="background-color:limegreen" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Purpose of **ValidateAntiForgeryToken** is to prevent cross-site request forgery attacks.

Add below line on your view

```
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()
```

Comment: thanks, i added this line.
but i still have the problem..